# How do I use regex to find and delete code in multiple files?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I need to find and delete the following strings in a large number of files.  Article ID and Session ID will be different in all files.  I plan to use a text editor, such as Notepad++.

```
<a href="https://example.com/edit/ArticleID/SessionID">Edit</a>

<a href="https://example.com/discuss/ArticleID/SessionID">Discuss</a>
```

How do I correctly formulate the regex for the 'Find' field?

**Edit**: per comments below, I am slightly rephrasing the strings that need to be replaced:

```
<a href="https://example.com/edit/WILDCARD">Edit</a>
```

Comment: What is the Find field? Can you please be more narrow with your question?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to find? Pattern and/or sample string? What are you trying to replace it with? An empty string to remove it?

Comment: Can you give us examples of strings that we shouldn't match? The way your current question is formulated, we could use `.*` to match the strings (probably not what you're looking for).

Comment: @Nilas The Find field in Notepad++'s "Find and replace tool."

Comment: @dvo I need to completely delete these lines of code

Comment: @ctwheels Everything after "edit/" and before ">Edit</a>" should be considered a wildcard.  I am not worried so much about the false positives because I will use the "find" command first (without "replace") to make sure that the count of discovered results matches the number of strings that need to be replaced (I already know that number).

Comment: Try this: `<a href=\"https:\/\/example.com\/.+?">[^\/]+<\/a>` If this isn't what you need, please further explain because it's unclear

Comment: [`<a[^>]+href="[^"]+/\K(([^/]+)/)[^"]*([^>]*>\2</a>)` replace with `$1WILDCARD$3`](https://regex101.com/r/g73Ahi/1) using `i` modifier (case-insensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<a href="https://example.com/edit/.+?Edit</a>`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<a href="https://example.com/edit/  # literally
.+?                                 # 1 or more any character but newline
Edit</a>                            # literally
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex: `^<a.*?>(Edit|Discuss)<\/a>$` to match the lines of text. See the example for further details: [link to regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ntYH4D/1)

make sure to use the `g` and `m` modifier.

Comment: I had to remove ^ from the beginning and $ from the end of the search strings, otherwise Notepad++ returned zero results.  I also added the full domain and URL portion, because only certain domains needed to be searched.